# REGEX - match list item followed by another list item 'n' times

Tags: python, regex

Suppose we have a list

`search_list = [one, two, three, four, five, six]`

and we want to match any item in this list which follows another item n times in the following string

`example string = This string has one two three and also five six in it`

How would we build a regex which can find all items which are adjacent to one another?

In this case, searching with re.findall, the output should be

```
[('one', 'two', 'three'), ('five', 'six')]
```

Here's what I've tried so far

Convert list into searchable string:

```
chain_regex = [re.escape(i) for i in search_list]
chain_regex = '|'.join(chain_re)
re.findall(f'({chain_regex})\s*({chain_regex})', example_string)
```

This works fine and produces the following output:

```
[('one', 'two'), ('five', 'six')]
```

Suppose I want to do this n times. How would you restructure this query so that it can be repeated without just chaining it indefinitely as below:

```
re.findall(f'({chain_regex})\s*({chain_regex})\s*({chain_regex})*\s*({chain_regex})*', example_string) etc....
```

**EDIT**

```
re.findall(f'({chain_re})(\s*({chain_re}))+', example_string)
```

produces the following output which isn't quite right.

```
[('one', ' three', 'three'), ('five', ' six', 'six')]
```

Chaining more and more items together *does* work however I can't always be sure of how many times I'd need to chain it together - this is where I'm stuck

Comment: `one two three` isn't adjacent to `five six` in your example. Is `one one two one` also a match?

Comment: @Chriz - thanks for replying to the question. I've updated it a bit and added an edit for clarity. Yes, in this case one one two one would match as it contains 2 elements from the list adjacent to one another 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with simple regex, but you have to filter the results:

```
import re

test1 = "This string has one two three and also five six in it"
reg = re.compile(r"(((one|two|three|four|five|six).?)*)")
match = re.findall(reg, test)
filtered = [m[0] for m in match if len(m[0].split(" ")) > 1]
filtered = [list(filter(None, f.split(' '))) for f in filtered]
filtered #[['one', 'two', 'three'], ['five', 'six']]
```

Example: (updated) https://regex101.com/r/YhlhRQ/4

Comment: good solution but failing fr `This string has one two three  one two and also five six in it` , fror this it should define 2 groups instead of 3

Comment: @temmo His example returns 2 matches, `one two three one two` and `five six`when I try it. If you want it to not return the group with the leading space, simply make it a non-capturing group: `(?: (one|two|three|four|five|six))+`

Comment: Thanks Jacek, I've updated the question a bit to better describe the outcome I want. Using the lookahead only captures 2 elements with output of `[('one', 'two'), ('two', 'three'), ('five', 'six')]`.  I'm looking for 'n' elements to be returned. In the `example_string `we have 3 elements from the list adjacent to one another in the string and another 2 elements together later in the string but we could equally have 15 elements next to each other if this makes sense?

Comment: Updated, As I've said, you have to do some post processing on the result to get list of unique values, Warning: There is one issue i haven't taught before, first element of next match can be exactly the same as last one from previous match, I am working on it